# @Html.DropDownListFor not applying selected to an option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

OK, So I have the code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, 
               new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status,
                          SalesHubb.Models.Lead.Statuses
                          .Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i, Value = i }))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
</div>
```

That correctly outputs a `<select>` with the proper `<option>` preselected on the page.

I also have the code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Model.Type
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, 
                          SalesHubb.Models.Task.Types
                          .Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i, Value = i }))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
</div>
```

That doesn't apply the `selected` property to the correct (or in fact, any)`<option>` in the resulting HTML. Both `SalesHubb.Models.Lead.Statuses` and `SalesHubb.Models.Task.Types` are `public static string[]`.

The only difference I can see is that the Model for the non-working page has been created by a conversion method (I have checked, all the data is correct and present in the model), whereas the working page is merely pulled from the database with `db.Leads.Find(id)`.

Any assistance would be great! I'm really stumped as to why two basically identical pieces of code don't work the same way.

Comment: what you mean by this: That doesn't apply the selected property to the correct

Comment: Did you try with: `new SelectListItem {Text=i, Value=1,Selected=(i==Model.Type)}` or something like that?

Comment: @Ehsan-Sajjad It's supposed to output an HTML `<select>` with `<option>`s built from the `List` I passed in, with the correct `<option>` as per the Model having the HTML `selected` attribute applied to it so that when the user loads the Edit page, the current value is preselected.

Comment: can you post the code where you are getting an populating this property:SalesHubb.Models.Task.Types

Comment: Here's the snippet from the `Task` class:
`public static string[] Types = new string[] { "Phone Call", "Email", "Meeting", "Other" };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the answer to my issue. I had a route value that was also called type that was overriding the model state value with something not on the list. This means that I couldn't preselect the value as it wasn't in the list. Renaming the route value solved the issue.